# Why DropDownList do not fire SelectedIndexChanged and select ALWAYS the first item on the list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback

I have 2 dropdownlists(ddlSchools and ddlDegrees) and 1 linkbutton to submit a query. Inside a updatePanel and both dropdownlists have autoPostBack = "true" and when ddlSchools change its index it calls LoadDegrees() to show the corresponding degrees offered in that School

The corresponding functions are
LoadSchools()
LoadDegrees()

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
      LoadSchools()
      LoadDegrees()
   End If
End Sub 

Protected Sub ddlSchool_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlSchool.SelectedIndexChanged           
    LoadDegrees()            
End Sub
```

Why always that i select other item in ddlDegrees other than the first it gets back to first? Even the SelectedIndexChanged event is not fired

Comment: try removing the autopostback="true" property on ddlDegrees if you're not doing anything on the select change

Comment: Does LoadDegrees() happen to have a DataBind() call in it?

Comment: @Sushil that of course work but then when i submit through the linkButton the value that is passed is always the first even when i have selected other in ddlDegree, in both scenarios i am lost

Comment: is there any other place where the LoadDegrees() function is called? try putting a break point in the LoadDegrees() function and debug. if it is getting changed from elsewhere, you'll be able to find it from the call stack.

Comment: @Gridly Yes but then when i remove tha autoPostback on ddlDegrees the problem is in submission through the linkButton, the value that is passed is always the first even when i have selected other in ddlDegree,

Comment: @Sushil only in those 2 places it is called

Comment: try commenting the LoadDegrees() function call in the page load since you're loading the degrees when the School is selected.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776840/Why-DropDownList-SelectedValue-Does-Not-Work-Insid), it may helps you.

Comment: Can you show all of the code in the code behind?  Specifically I am looking if there is a selected index change method for ddlDegree, but maybe if we can see the rest of the code behind we can spot what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect the change you have to actually have differente values for the DataValueField property to fire up the event.